# SQLite - How To add a column to multiple tables?

Tags: sql, sqlite

I get a syntax error when I'm trying to add "one" column to  multiple tables.

`ALTER TABLE x , y add column z INT;`

I get : `near ",": syntax error`

I tried this code below but it doesn't work either :

`ALTER TABLE (SELECT * FROM x, y) add column z INT;`

Error: `near "(": syntax error`

is there any way to do that just by sqlite3 interface?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

SQLite's ALTER TABLE can only alter one table at a time, so you'd have to add the columns to each table individually, i.e.

```
ALTER TABLE x ADD COLUMN z INT;
ALTER TABLE y ADD COLUMN z INT;
```

Comment: This looks easy for two tables but what about 100 tables? there is no way?

Comment: Not using SQLite's alter table on its own. If you are writing a script to update these tables, then the easiest way would be to iterate through a list of the table names you wish to change, and execute an ALTER TABLE for each one. You could populate that list via a SELECT on the sqlite_master table, i.e. `SELECT name FROM sqlite_master WHERE type='table';`

Comment: well select is not working ...
like ALTER TABLE (SELECT x,y FROM sqlite_master where type ='table') add column z INT

Comment: ALTER TABLE will take one, and only one, table name. So you need to run ALTER TABLE once for each name returned by that SELECT statement. Are you writing a script/program to do this? Are you using the SQLite command line interface?

Comment: 1. I'm learning how to do this.
2. I'm using notepade for editing my SQL databases.
3. I'm running them on terminal with sqlite3 compilable version.

Comment: Unfortunately, the SQLite terminal interface does not support batch ALTER TABLE commands. That is, you have to write and run them one by one. You'd have to write a script to automate the process, or use a third-party SQLite client